# How to call Django model method from admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have a model that is seperate to a user model which stores passwords, I have implemented a `set_password` method on that model, and this works ok, the only place I am facing issues is the admin panel, if I try to update a password in the model from the admin it does not call this `set_password` method. Instead it inputs the password as plain text. Is there a way to override the admin panel so it calls the `set_password` method?

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   created_on = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
   encrypted_pass = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)

   def set_password(self, raw_password):
       self.encrypted_pass = make_password(raw_password)
```

Comment: Could be good idea to consult with documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model

Comment: try to use Signals on post_save or pre_save.did you try this ?

Comment: @iklinac I did check this out, however I am not substituting my User model as I have that set up as well. This is another password for another section of the site.

Comment: @amadousow I did look into signals but I thought to avoid it as they tend to decouple code from things triggering. But not entirely sure I will have a read through again.

Comment: You can override default ModelAdmin form with your own in which you would override save method. make sure you have inputs of password type and do not show even hashed password in admin